# Changing an ExpressionEngine Plugin's Parse Order

Tags: expressionengine

I have the following ExpressionEngine code in a template:

```
{exp:hits:count_hits_image entry_id='{exp:test:getpage tag="id"}'}
```

Where `exp:test` is a plugin I created to get a [channel entry's ID](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#entry-id).

The problem I'm having is that `exp:hits` is being parsed *before* `exp:test`, which makes the whole tag disfunctional.

What can I do to tell ExpressionEngine to parse the inside tag first `{exp:test}`, before parsing the outside tag `{exp:hits}`?

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is turn your plugin into a tag pair, so it works like this:

```
{exp:test:getpage tag="id" parse="inward"}
    {exp:hits:count_hits_image entry_id='{id}'}
{/exp:test:getpage}
```

In your plugin you'd do something like this:

```
$vars = array();
$vars[0]['id'] = $results->row('id');
return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In my code, do i just replace `return $results->row('id');` with `return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $results);` so that i can have tag pair with variable {id}. Is there anything else i'm missing. I can't get it to work.

Comment: I just updated my code example to more accurately match your existing code.

Comment: Thanks derek, we are almost there. Double pair works now and I can see the id if i do `{exp:test:getpage tag="id" parse="inward"}{id}{/exp:test:getpage}` but if i do as per your tag code above like so `{exp:test:getpage tag="id" parse="inward"}
    {exp:hits:count_hits_image entry_id='{id}'}
{/exp:test:getpage}` then i get a blank page. I confirmed that the hit tag is working by hard coding the id. It just doesn't work when i wrap it with the getpage tag. What do you think is the problem

Comment: Do you mean you get a blank page as in there's an error? (Would you usually have other content appearing in the template?) If so, enable debug in your index.php file and see what the PHP error is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
{exp:hits:count_hits_image entry_id='{exp:test:getpage tag="id"}' parse="inward"}
```

Comment: This does opposite of what i need. it processed the outside first.